# Styles not being passed to body element

Tags: html, css

I have looked at lots of different answers to similar questions and cant seem to find the answer anywhere. The question is simple, why are my #body styles not being applied. Basically I just want a background color to be applied. Interestingly, none of the styles are actually being passed to from the CSS to the body. The code is simple but not working.

When i use "inspect element" i can see that all my other styles are working fin but nothing is being passed to the body element and I cant figure it out!

I'm sure its something really simple but would appreciate your help on this one. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
  <body>

    <div id="header">
      <div id="contact_bar">
```

CSS is:

```
#body{
background-color:red;
}

#header{
background-color: #3862C6;
height:500px;
}
#contact_bar{
background-color: #020731;
height:150px;
}
```

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `#body{...`  , but `body{...` (without the "#")

Comment: Thanks for this... I noticed as soon as I had posted

Answer (score 0):

What an idiot.... as soon as I poseted i notice the "#" infront of body....

Answer (score 0):

You should know that in CSS # is used to style id elements, but body is HTML tag and it should be styled as per the CSS given in this answer.
Your HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
  <body>

    <div id="header">
      <div id="contact_bar">
```

CSS should be:

```
body{
background-color:red;
}

#header{
background-color: #3862C6;
height:500px;
}
#contact_bar{
background-color: #020731;
height:150px;
}
```